# ¿Cerrar una pregunta cuyo problema es no incluir librerías correctamente?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

En referencia a esta pregunta de SOes: "[Animaciones css3 con animation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5197/animaciones-css3-con-animation)" (aunque estoy seguro de que podría encontrar más). El usuario pregunta por qué falla ese código y la solución propuesta es simple: la URL de uno de los ficheros es incorrecta, así que no se carga y por eso no funciona.

Personalmente, yo consideraría esto equivalente a un fallo tipográfico y lo categorizaría dentro de la [siguiente definición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Preguntas acerca de un problema que ya no puede ser reproducido o que se debió a un simple error tipográfico. Aunque preguntas similares pueden ser pertinentes aquí, estas con frecuencia son resueltas de forma tal que es poco probable sean de ayuda a otros usuarios en el futuro. Esto puede ser muchas veces evitado al identificar e inspeccionar con cuidado el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el problema antes de publicar la pregunta.

Pero, ¿es ese el caso o sería demasiado estricto si pido el cierre? Y si lo pidiese, ¿es "Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda" el motivo adecuado?

Comment: Su pregunta es interesante, pero creo que podrian darse varias situaciones, 1 en que el usuario olvido algun parametro/caracter dentro de la ruta por ejemplo un '/' y se puede asumir que el autor sabe como manejar este tipo de situaciones pero no se dio cuenta, o 2 por ejemplo que el autor tiene un error en la ruta, pero no sabe como referirse a esta, (no se si es el caso de esa pregunta) , en el que puede ver que @jasilva comenta -> Asegúrate que tu archivo que descargaste este al mismo nivel de tu html........

Comment: explicandole al respecto sobre su posible error. En el caso 1, creo que se podria incluir en lo que usted comenta como fallo tipografico, en el caso 2, creo que seria igual que una pregunta en la cual no se sabe como solucionar, pues el usuario no saber como manejar los ficheros. Solo es mi opinion. Saludos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opino que depende. El problema es de inclusión de librerías. En el caso de aplicaciones web, sobretodo en HTML, la única manera de agregar librerías y recursos es escribir la URL del recurso manualmente, lo cual puede llevar a estas situaciones.

Si el error se debe a que se confundió al escribir una palabra p.e. `urlconmuhcoscaracteres` cuando era `urlconmuchoscaracteres` (nótese la palabra muhcos vs muchos en las urls) entonces, en mi opinión, es un **error tipográfico** puesto que no ayuda a nadie más que aquel que publicó la pregunta, la pregunta y la respuesta no agregan ningún valor a otros lectores.

Si el error se debe a que no se ubicaron bien los recursos en el servidor y la URL falla, p.e. cuando se tiene la sgte estructura:

```
- recursos
  - css
    - ext
      + estilos.css
    + estilos.css
```

Y existe una confusión entre cual de los recursos utilizar en la URL, en mi opinión, es una pregunta válida que requiere la atención y apoyo de la comunidad puesto que se puede realizar un análisis sobre el problema y las explicaciones en la solución pueden ayudar a cualquier futuro lector de este recurso.

En el caso de la pregunta que indicas, jasilva explica por qué sucede el problema y cómo se puede arreglar utilizando dos maneras. Para mí, esa pregunta y respuesta ayudan a otros miembros de la comunidad. Por ende, la pregunta no debería ser cerrada.