# ¿Se puede decidir en Meta?

Tags: discusión, meta

Meta es útil. Se puede comunicar, documentar el sitio y resolver dudas. Se deciden algunas cosas como las ciudades de las celebraciones.

Pero, ¿puede la comunidad tomar decisiones en Meta sobre cómo debe ser el sitio?

Algún esfuerzo ha habido en esta dirección: [¿Cómo deberíamos gestionar las propuestas en Meta para que sus respuestas/encuestas tengan efecto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2093/c%C3%B3mo-deber%C3%ADamos-gestionar-las-propuestas-en-meta-para-que-sus-respuestas-encues) Pero no puede llegar a ninguna parte sin la sanción del sitio.

Y peor aún, y lo que me lleva a escribir esto, el proceso de toma de decisiones de la comunidad en Meta es saboteado. Me refiero a [Reabriendo:¿Cómo funciona el preprocesador de C++?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2184/reabriendo-c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-preprocesador-de-c)
El tema iba por buen camino. Un moderador, ArtEze, poniendo dos respuestas tipo encuesta que encaminaban a que la comunidad pudiese decidir algo en Meta. Inicialmente los votos se decantan por el NO y ArtEze recierra la pregunta pese a que él está a favor de abrirla. ¡Bravo! El respeto se demuestra respetando a quien no concuerda contigo, poco mérito tiene respetar a aquel con quien coincides.
4 días despues el NO sigue siendo mayoría pero otro moderador,  Luiggi Mendoza, la reabre.

Tras pedirle que la deje cerrada respetando la actual decisión de la comunidad su [contestación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2184/reabriendo-c%C3%B3mo-funciona-el-preprocesador-de-c/2187?noredirect=1#comment6876_2187) es:

> la decisión de meta se basó en votar por la pregunta en el estado en
>   que estaba. Luego de eso y con mi respuesta, sinceramente no sé qué es
>   lo que realmente la comunidad decida. Nuevamente, si la pregunta debe
>   ser cerrada, la comunidad puede votar a cierre de la misma o
>   reportarla para su cierre. Ese es el poder de la comunidad.

La decisión de la comunidad en esa cuestión siempre a sido cerrar. Siempre han sido mayoría los votos a cerrar.
¿Es esta la medida de la importancia que tiene la opinión de la comunidad en Meta?

Comment: Me parece que intentas generar controversia apuntando hacia mi decisión como moderador. Si vemos la línea de tiempo de esa pregunta, las últimas operaciones de apertura y cierre y reapertura fueron hechas por moderadores, no por votos de la comunidad como dices. Y fueron hechas inclusive sin tú haber elegido la respuesta (la cual considero que sería la decisión final luego de unos días de espera de que la comunidad vote). Ni siquiera en eso hay un orden. Así que, yo opto por dejar la pregunta abierta nuevamente y que si **la comunidad realmente quiere cerrarla** que vote hacia ello.

Comment: En esto, también lanzo un mensaje para otros moderadores: **no debemos votar a abrir/cerrar este tipo de publicaciones mientras sigan en disputa**. En su lugar, lo que se debe hacer es bloquear la publicación y que quede así hasta que se tome la decisión en meta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La polémica la creas tu con tu actuación. Yo pido que se respete la decisión de la mayoría. Que es objetivamente, por 6 contra 5, cerrar.

Comment: A eso me refiero: no veo opinión de la mayoría. Los votos que yo vi a favor de cerrar la pregunta eran sobre el estado actual de ella. La actualizaste, pero **en ningún momento vi** una nueva respuesta que sea **votar por la pregunta para dejarla abierta con el nuevo estado**. Nuevamente, la votación carece de orden. ¿Qué resultado esperas realmente? Ahora, si los votos de mantener abierta la pregunta se suman a la de mi propuesta de mantener la pregunta abierta con un nuevo estado, eso hace más que los 6 por dejarla cerrada. ¿Qué decidir entonces?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ¿Entonces yo tengo derecho a votar dos veces? No puedes sumar los votos de esas dos respuestas. Si se pudiesen fusionar eliminado votos repetidos y el resultado fuese más de 6 entonces tendría sentido tu postura. La opción más votada tiene 6 votos, es un hecho objetivo. El resto son especulaciones.

Comment: Por eso mismo, no veo un orden. Al no ver orden, realmente no veo un resultado final para esa pregunta. Recomendaría volver a iniciar la votación y en base a ese nuevo resultado, decidir.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Hasta que interveniste tu el orden estaba muy claro. Dos respuestas, una para abrir, otra para cerrar; la pregunta se dejaba cerrada, que es como los votos de cierre comunitario orignalmente habían decidido, mientras se decidía. Pero incluso con tu desorden sigue estando claro que 6>5 y 6>3. A ver qué dice otra gente.

Comment: En realidad, en ese tipo de publicaciones no se cuentan los votos negativos a las respuestas. Así, que sería 6 < 5 + 3. Igual, si lo que quieres es que se cierre la pregunta, acabo de hacerlo. "Respetaré el orden" que indicas.

Comment: Coincido con @LuiggiMendoza en que los moderadores deben mantenerse al margen de la decisión hasta que esta esté clara. Lo que me sorprende es que no tengáis una manera interna de comunicaros para definir comportamientos colectivos. Por si es útil, en [spanish.se] los moderadores tenemos un chat privado donde vamos comentando los [pocos] temas que van surgiendo de este tipo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Gracias. Voy a suponer que no me malinterpretas a propósito. Primero, yo no quiero que se cierre, lo que quiero es que se respete la mayoría, incluso cuando la mayoría es contraria a mi opinión como es el caso (yo pedí que se abriera). Segundo, yo no he contado negativos y ya he explicado que no puedes sumar 5+3 pues eso significaría que habría gente votando 2 veces.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos me malinterpretas. Yo comento que no hay orden, y lo que tú incitas es más desorden. La verdad, no cedo a tu presión ni a la de la gente. Si mantener esa pregunta cerrada les hace feliz, que así sea.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Respetar a la mayoría no es ceder. Cambia el chip.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos por última vez. No veo mayoría (y si te digo que no veo es porque realmente veo **diferentes votos** [sí, distintas personas]) votando por las cosas. Y tomar decisión sobre el desorden, simplemente **no se puede**, ni siquiera hay mayoría porque es desorden. ¿Qué esperas? Solo haré lo que sea más práctico y haga menos desorden. Si eso es tener tu pregunta cerrada, que así sea. No porque la mayoría, no porque has publicado esta pregunta. Si eso es orden, que se cierre.

Comment: No termino de entender por qué se tiene que decidir el abrir/cerrar una pregunta de SOes en meta. ¿No existen ya métodos para ello en la propia comunidad sin necesidad de tener que recurrir a meta?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Parece que sí lo entendías en [¿Cerrar una pregunta cuyo problema es no incluir librerías correctamente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/491/cerrar-una-pregunta-cuyo-problema-es-no-incluir-librer%C3%ADas-correctamente)

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Hay una diferencia abismal entre pedir que se cierre/reabra una pregunta, y pedir opinión de la gente sobre cómo sería la mejor manera de actuar en un tipo de errores bastante recurrente. Lo primero es quitar autoridad/legitimidad a los usuarios que votaron porque la pregunta se cerrase/reabriese usando las herramientas ya disponibles para ello. Lo segundo es un simple usuario (yo mismo) con una duda y pidiendo opinión sobre cuál sería la mejor opción, sin pedir a nadie que haga lo uno o lo otro.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro a mí sí me parece correcto plantear un tema así en Meta, sobre todo ahora que estamos comenzando. Se parte de un caso concreto y, bien debatido, puede crear líneas maestras sobre qué tipo de preguntas y respuestas queremos y aceptamos. Dejarlo al azar de las colas de revisión puede funcionar, pero veo totalmente razonable pedir una "revisión extra" más fundamentada. Eso sí, creo que caímos demasiado rápido en el "vota por el sí / vota por el no", cuando la respuesta de Luiggi allí (ahora borrada) ahondaba más en el tema de cómo mejorarla, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui El problema de raíz que veo es que esas preguntas (de "votemos aquí por reabrir/cerrar") directamente no deberían ocurrir en meta. No se debería "votar sí / votar no" en meta, porque ya existen herramientas en el sitio para eso ("votos de reapertura / votos de cierre"). Esas preguntas no tratan de crear líneas maestras, en ellas se está decidiendo si una pregunta debería ser abierta o cerrada por un moderador en ese momento, en contra de la voluntad de otros usuarios que votaron por otro curso de acción.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro comparto tu punto en cuanto a que "votar sí / votar no" pasa por encima la decisión soberana que ya hizo la comunidad. Lo que yo agradezco de estas preguntas es la aproximación que tenía la respuesta de Luiggi en cuanto a _qué se puede modificar para que se pueda reabrir_.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Si relees mi pregunta en Meta te encontrarás con: *¿Qué cambio en la pregunta para que sea aceptable?*. Pedí, recibí y seguí consejo sobre como mejorar la pregunta. Meta sí es para eso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sí**

En meta los usuarios podemos decidir sobre asuntos relativos a la gestión de Stack Overflow en Español: errores, sugerencias, comentarios, peticiones de nuevas funcionalidades, voto para moderadores...

Y también sobre acciones que han ocurrido en la comunidad: *¿Por qué me cerraron esta pregunta?*, *¿Cuál fue el criterio para este voto positivo/negativo?*,  *¿Por qué no me deja comentar?*, *¿Por qué se bloqueó mi cuenta?*, *Voté por reabrir esta pregunta ¿quién está conmigo?**...

**...y No**

Meta no es el sitio para se "arreglen" votos con los que no estoy de acuerdo de Stack Overflow en Español. Para eso ya existen herramientas a disposición de la propia comunidad: votos negativos/positivos, votos de cierre, reportes, votos de reapertura, ediciones...

**Si una herramienta está disponible en la comunidad, se debería usar esa herramienta para solucionar el problema y no recurrir a meta**. ¿Quiero que una pregunta se cierre/reabra? Voto por cerrar/reabrir o edito la pregunta para que esté más clara; y que sea la comunidad, los propios usuarios usando las colas de revisión, la que tome esa decisión.

Sé que ahora alguien dirá "*pero también son los usuarios los que deciden en meta*", lo cual será cierto, aunque con matices. Uno: no son los usuarios los que deciden, son los moderadores los que finalmente toman la acción los que deciden... y a veces puede no ocurrir como los usuarios esperan (como en el caso que se expone en la pregunta).

Y dos (y me llamaréis clasista): los privilegios. Se supone que los usuarios ganan experiencia conforme usan el sitio. Más uso, más experiencia, más privilegios para decidir dentro de la comunidad. Estas preguntas de "vota sí/vota no" le están quitando legitimidad y autoridad a los usuarios que votaron por reabrir/cerrar preguntas (3000+ puntos) y lo están decidiendo usuarios cuyo único privilegio puede ser acceder a meta (5 puntos). Se cargan de un plumazo todo el sistema de puntos y privilegios en el que se sustentan los sitios de Stack Exchange.

---

**Voté por reabrir esta pregunta ¿quién está conmigo?* puede parecer que va en contra de la segunda parte de mi respuesta, pero no realmente. La idea sería enlazar la pregunta, plantear el caso (*creo que fue incorrectamente cerrada/reabierta por esto, esto y lo otro*) y pedir a los usuarios con derecho a voto (que no a los moderadores) que voten en el sitio, no en meta.

Las respuestas a esa pregunta podrían ser explicaciones más detalladas de por qué se debería votar a favor o en contra de cerrar/reabrir. Y no directamente un voto de cierre/reapertura.

Comment: Es un buen argumento que hay unos privilegios para abrir y cerrar. Pero esos privilegios son una muestra de la confianza que tiene el sitio en esas personas para aplicar unas normas y costumbres que ya existen, no son para sentar nuevos precedentes. ¿Y el privilegio de establecer cuales son esas normas y costumbres? ¿A quién corresponde?

Answer (score 2):

@Luiggi es un buen compañero, pero acá los moderadores tenemos algo llamado **autodestrucción de contenido útil**, y eso sería un problema, borró su respuesta. De todos modos el proceso de la votación a la respuesta de @Luiggi se finalizó cuando se editó la pregunta, y la dejamos en wiki de comunidad.

Pienso que a pesar de la votación de la gente por cerrarla, me parece una buena pregunta para mantener en el sitio. Si yo pudiera votarme a mí mismo, ahora la votación estaría en 5 contra 6. Mirando que es casi un empate, creo que estaría bien dejarla abierta.

Piensa, que te debió haber costado un montón responderla. Perder eso sería una lástima.

Comment: A mi me gustaría que se abriese. Por eso hice la pregunta original. Pero es solo una respuesta y que se pierda tiene poca importancia. Que un moderador haga una encuesta en meta y luego se salte el resultado de su propia encuesta sí me parece que tiene importancia. Seamos pacientes.